# Remove last part of URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove last part of some urls that end with lang,fr-fr/ using htaccess
 i have tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)lang,fr-fr/ $1 [L]
```

but no luck
Your help will be so much appreciated,
Thank you

Comment: What is the original full URL and what do you want as final URL?

Comment: It's somewhat unclear to me what you want. Do you want the url in the browser to be changed?

Comment: Hi, i want to change  http://www.example.com/guestbook/lang,fr-fr/ to http://www.example.com/guestbook and http://www.example.com/forum/lang,fr-fr/ to http://www.example.com/forum and http://www.example.com/downloads/lang,fr-fr/ to http://www.example.com/downloads